# Creating a rails route with dot characters on it: Like myapp.com/sites/mysite.com.mx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a rails 5 app that will have one url for each site using it: 
Example: http://myapp.com/sites/mysite.com.br

How would I do that?

Comment: You can treat mysite.com.br as a friendly id of sites model

Answer (score 0):

You can use [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It is really simple.
Other way (hack) can be define sites object uniquely and define a normal route

> get '/sites/:site_initials', to: 'sites#show'

Make sure your first portion of `mysite.com.br` (mysite) is uniq. When you pass it in url you will get `mysite in params[:site_initials]` on your controller now you can do whatever you want.